# Proftpd with TLS not working on CentOS

Tags: centos, openssl, tls, proftpd

Since last month update, Proftpd with TLS not working anymore on Centos 5.11 and Centos 6.7. While trying to connect with FileZilla client, it gets stuck at "Initializing TLS..."

Installed Openssl and proftpd version on CentOS 5.11:

```
openssl-0.9.8e-36.0.1.el5_11
proftpd-1.3.3g-4.el5
```

Installed Openssl and proftpd version on CentOS 6.7:

```
openssl-1.0.1e-42.el6.x86_64
proftpd-1.3.3g-6.el6.x86_64
```

Proftpd config file TLS settings:

```
<IfDefine TLS>
  TLSEngine                     off
  TLSRequired                   off
  TLSRSACertificateFile         /etc/pki/ssl.cert
  TLSRSACertificateKeyFile      /etc/pki/ssl.key
  TLSCACertificateFile          /etc/pki/ssl.ca
  TLSProtocol                   SSLv3 TLSv1
#  TLSCipherSuite               ALL:!ADH:!DES
  TLSOptions                    AllowClientRenegotiations NoSessionReuseRequired
  TLSVerifyClient               off
  #TLSRenegotiate               ctrl 3600 data 512000 required off timeout 300
  TLSLog                        /var/log/proftpd/tls.log
 <IfModule mod_tls_shmcache.c>
    TLSSessionCache             shm:/file=/var/run/proftpd/sesscache
  </IfModule>
</IfDefine>
```

The certificate used is CA signed certificate. I tried with TLSProtocol TLSv1.1 and TLSv1.2, but proftpd not starting.

I have one CentOS 5.11 box which has Openssl version openssl-0.9.8e-34.el5_11 installed and FTP with TLS working fine on that box.

I have seen same issue while trying to connect to some other FTP location which is hosted by other hosting companies.

Thanks.

Comment: please add the specific logfiles, so one can see why the service is not starting.

Answer (score 0):

The latest available version for Centos (1.3.3g), as Spectre already said, seems to not work correctly with TLS 1.1/1.2

See the following link for having at least some notes about a potential fix for those issues beeing in Version 1.3.5

> http://www.proftpd.org/docs/RELEASE_NOTES-1.3.5a

Qoute: `TLS 1.1/1.2 configuration now works properly.`

So it seems your option is to compile the new version yourself.

Answer (score -1):

Same Problem here.

It seems that the current Version (1.3.3g) of ProFTPd doesn't support >tls1.0 and the filezilla guys dropped the tls1.0 Support.

Unfortunately i can't find any information in the Docs of neither Filezilla  nor ProFTPd, so that's just a guess.

Comment: current version seems to be not 1.3.3g but 1.3.5a
http://www.proftpd.org/docs/RELEASE_NOTES-1.3.5a
Tls is mentioned for 1.3.5
1.3.5
---------

  + TLS 1.1/1.2 configuration now works properly.

Comment: We're talking about CentOS... In This Case it's the current version -.-